# Need Xamarin CollectionView Behavior to Run Again

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, behavior, collectionview, bindable

I created a behavior that sizes my `collectionview` rows to prevent the collectionview from invoking its own scrolling behavior and for preventing too much space after the last row.

XAML

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="-55,0,0,0">

    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="0"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

    <CollectionView.Behaviors>
        <core:CollectionViewRectangleVerticleHeightBehavior/>
    </CollectionView.Behaviors>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ....
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Class file (not code behind)

```
public class CollectionViewRectangleVerticleHeightBehavior : Behavior<CollectionView>
{
    bool hasHeightChanged = false;

    public CollectionView CollectionViewObject { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(CollectionView bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        CollectionViewObject = bindable;
        bindable.BindingContextChanged += Bindable_BindingContextChanged;
        bindable.SizeChanged += Bindable_SizeChanged;
    }

    ...

    private void Bindable_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!hasHeightChanged)
        {
            if (CollectionViewObject.BindingContext is Grouping<string,Estimate> grp)
            {
                CollectionViewObject.HeightRequest = (grp.Count * (32 + grp.Count == 1 ? 0 : 66 + 50));
                hasHeightChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

It works fine with the initial data given to `ItemsSource`. However, when I add records to the `ObservableCollection` in the viewmodel, the behavior is not run again thereby causing a scroll bar to appear.

How do I force the `CollectionView` to "redraw" itself so that the Behavior is run again? Ideally, an event would fire if the scrollbar is about to appear and a expose a method to invoke the behavior for the current row. I don't find anything like that in reality.

Comment: I don't understand, why you want to force the layout to hide scroll, adding more items for sure it will enable scroll, consider also the different screen sizes that maybe would need scroll. By the other hand you can set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` properties to `Never` in order to hide the scrollbars, and maybe add `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView"`, but it will not prevent the scroll.

Comment: The whole page can scroll. I just do not want adding or removing of items in the collectionview to only occupy its original space. I want it to grow as needed so it does not invoke its own scrolling behavior.

Comment: Since you are just changing the heightrequest of CollectionViewObject in the behavior, why not change it at  the point you adding or removing of items in the collectionview?

Comment: The add/remove happens in the viewmodel, which doesn't have access to the collectionview.

Comment: Binding the heightrequest with a property in the VM and update this property when add/remove happens in the viewmodel.

Comment: I gave this a try but didn't like it much because it forces the VM to have knowledge of the contents of the ItemTemplates. Eventaully I abandoned the CollectionView in favor of StackLayout BindableLayout. This works far better for small (200 ish) number of rows. I really wish CollectionView offered auto resizable option.